# Alternative to SendKeys Enter for activating cells in excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I'm pasting some dates from a csv file into excel using a macro, and using a find/replace to alter the format into one excel can recognise, from 2019_10_22_08_43_23 to 22/10/2019 08:43:23, for example. Excel won't recognise this text as a date until you manually select the cell and press enter, and therefore won't display the dates on a graph correctly until this has been done. My current solution is using

```
For Each c In cycleRange.Cells
c.Select 
SendKeys "{F2}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
Next
```

to manually press enter in each cell but this takes quite a long time. I have tried using TextToColumns but this isn't working. If I manually select the cell range, and navigate the data menu to click TextToColumn myself it corrects the cell format, but doing this through a macro doesn't do anything.

```
cycleRange.Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=cycleRange, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

What's the fastest method to replace looping through each cell and using Sendkeys to activate them?

Comment: If it's a contiguous range, use: `cycleRange.Formula = cycleRange.value`

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by this? I've added that line and nothing changed, should I be calling it on each cell in my loop

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert each cell to number. Here is the code:

```
Dim cellValue As Double

For Each c In cycleRange.Cells
    If IsNumeric(c.Text) Then
        cellValue = c.Value
        c.Clear
        c.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        c = Val(c.Text)
        ' c = c.Text * 1
        ' c = CDbl(c.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not a number (" & c.Address & ")")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this just gives "not a number" for each cell and doesn't correct the formatting

Comment: Maybe you have a different formatting on your PC? "." (dot) instead of "," (comma) or otherwise? Also, please make sure you don't have any other characters (like space) in your cells to convert it to number.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to combine the string conversion and cell formatting into one VBA operation

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim dat() As String
    
    Set rng = [A1:A10] ' update to suit your needs
    
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Value2 Like "####_##_##_##_##_##" Then
            dat = Split(cl.Value2, "_")
            cl = DateSerial(dat(0), dat(1), dat(2)) + TimeSerial(dat(3), dat(4), dat(5))
            cl.NumberFormat = "yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" ' update to suit your required format
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simulate to enter a cell and push enter by replacing a specific number by itself i.e. you replace 1 by 1. As such, the format changes. Doing this for 0, 1, then 2 up to 9 will cover all your cells, whatever figure is in the cell.

Here a macro:

```
Sub Repl1by1()
    Cells.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="1", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="2", Replacement:="2", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="3", Replacement:="3", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="4", Replacement:="4", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="5", Replacement:="5", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="6", Replacement:="6", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="7", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="8", Replacement:="8", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="9", Replacement:="9", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _ :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```